# Terraform aws eks worker node spot instance

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks

I am following this blog to run terraform to spin up an eks cluster .
https://github.com/berndonline/aws-eks-terraform/blob/master/

I just want to change my ec2 worker node type to spot instance 
https://github.com/berndonline/aws-eks-terraform/blob/master/eks-worker-nodes.tf
I googled and narrowed it down to launch configuration section,

any ideas how to change the ec2 type to spot instance ?

Comment: whoever voted down , have you tried doing this , it is not straight forward as you think , if it is provide the solution and then you can vote this down

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the official document about resource [aws_launch_configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/launch_configuration.html)

it gives you the sample on how to set spot instance already:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "as_conf" {
  image_id      = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  instance_type = "m4.large"
  spot_price    = "0.001"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

#### Notes:

spot instances price are keep changing depend on the usage. If you are not  familiar with it, use the same price of its on-demond price.

Even you set as on-demond price, AWS will only charge you less (normally 5 times less), unless they are used out. But AWS will never charge more.

Please also go through aws document for details: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/

Comment: spot_price="0.001" is just an example ,how do i get spot instance price ? and how can i defer it to on demand once spot instance expires , thnx

Comment: Regarding spot price, I added note in my answer. for your second question, it has no chance to switch back to on-demond instance, when spot instances are used out. You can set two pools, for example, one for on-demond (1 - x), one for spot instances (0 - 20), so it will always have at least one on-demond instance running.

Comment: ,how do i set two pools , the Terraform docs just shows how to set up eithier spot inst or on demand , but not both , can you share skeleton code .. thnx

Comment: Hi, @user17970 did you progress with this problem statement? I'm also looking for a solution for a similar problem statement

Comment: @coderhere, I was not able to do a mix and match , but I was able to change workernodes.tf node type to spot and specify a price , keep it high enough or you could keep it same as on demand , aws will only charge lowest spot inst price for that region , good luck hope this helps